# Moderators, users wants to delete some question, leave them!

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> Post Deleted by Braiam, Eric Carvalho, Avinash Raj, Radu Rădeanu, fossfreedom♦
>
> Post Deleted by Braiam, Eric Carvalho, Radu Rădeanu, fossfreedom♦
>
> Post Deleted by Braiam, Eric Carvalho, Avinash Raj, Radu Rădeanu, fossfreedom♦
>
> Post Deleted by Braiam, Eric Carvalho, Radu Rădeanu, fossfreedom♦

All ends with:

> Post Undeleted by fossfreedom♦

Yeah, I see the pattern.

There are 4 users that wants to delete a question, use their votes to reach that point, and why is a moderator overriding it? It takes time, **very much time** to delete stuff. A question that gathered 4 delete votes means that there's something wrong with the question. Please, **deleting is a right granted to us 10kers.** Don't override our decision if we find those questions are not good for the site. We can manage.

Is sad that we aren't more proactive and veer to the shy side of the tools.

- https://askubuntu.com/posts/8209/revisions
- https://askubuntu.com/posts/247/revisions
- https://askubuntu.com/posts/42532/revisions
- https://askubuntu.com/posts/48299/revisions

Comment: Funny thing is that even if Radu and I don't agree in certain things, we at least agree here.

Comment: It would help greatly if you could post the links to the posts; and downvoters, it helps immensely when you post the reason too. It takes courage to post something pointing out a moderator's activity, even more when he is the highest rep user and even more when he is @fossfreedom ;)

Comment: @Jobin there....

Comment: Oh damn... I forgot I am not a 10ker :( You know what!

Comment: @Jobin the revisions shows it all. What you are not seeing.

Comment: I can only see the title and who and what was revised.

Comment: I am sorry, I can see them, sorry.

Comment: You're taking as if mods don't get a say in this... Try not to forget that we're also users... Users who have been here a while. Foss has earnt the 10k voting rights almost ten times now.

Comment: @Oli yeah, but that's not reason to clear out others users votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you've been around the site for a while, you'll find that links to questions in Meta tend to garner many more views than normal.

- [Please do not delete closed questions with many views and many upvotes](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9132/please-do-not-delete-closed-questions-with-many-views-and-many-upvotes)

When it comes to asking about deleting stuff, it's human nature to say to one's self - "I'm going to exercise my right here" ... even before the community has themselves decided whether something has to - collectively - go or stay.

In the Meta question - this is exactly what has happened.  Deleted votes started gathering speed before the community itself had decided.

Thus to action - as community moderator I'm here to ensure the smooth running of the site.

In this case, ensuring users who do not have the visibility of deleted questions (less than 10K) actually know what those questions are all about.  They themselves have an equal right to express either a comment or an answer as to what to do with those questions.

Hence - whilst I could have "locked" the question, this itself will have the negative consequence of preventing everyones right of voting up or down.

So - to ensure smooth running, I cancelled the gathering storm of deletion.  Once the community meta question has been answered, we can then follow the guidance given.

If the community decides "bye bye" to those questions, community mods can safely delete the questions without further resort to the "must have 5" criteria.

Comment: Actually the delete votes are "must have between 3 to 10" criteria (most of the question listed needed at least other 4-6 users to agree to be deleleted). On the other side, those votes has ages there. Most of them I voted has over 3 months.